Retrieve email of author associated with Google Drive Comment
Is there any way to associated a comment on a Google Drive file with a user email. The author field in the Comment object does not have a permissionId or emailAddress field.
Trying to match a displayName with a user returned from the about.get endpoint is not ideal due to the possibilities of non-unique display names. The photoLink cannot be used either to create a unique key since the photo links returned from about.get and from the comment object are different, even if they are referencing the same photo.
It seems very bizarre to me that we cannot correlate a comment with a user email. Is there any workaround to this?

Just to clarify, is this comment in a specific file of Google drive? or a comment within Google sheets, or docs, etc?

This question is similar to: How to check the identity of the person who added a Google Doc comment. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The reason I linked the question is because the workaround to this is the answer in the question, which is to use Method: about.get and compare the displayName or photoLink with it. The author in REST Resource: comments also states that The author's email address and permission ID will not be populated., indicating that this is to be expected.

If that doesn't work for you, I found a Feature Request on Google's Issue Tracker called Get author's email in comments. You can support this by clicking the +1 button on the upper right of the page, letting Google know that you'd also like this feature.
